# Excel VBA - Get Link from HTML Anchor Where There is No ID Getting [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to get the href value from a link on a webpage, where the anchor tag does not have an ID.

The method that I'm using below returns [object HTMLDivElement] as the value for aEle. How do I get the actual link from the anchor tag within the h2 class="title" tag?

The HTML looks like this:

```
 <div id="searchResults" class="searchResults_clear">
  <div class="prodFeatures>
    <div class="inner">
      <a title="Product Name 1" class="img" href="/product1.html"><img alt='' src="/products/product1.jpg" /></a>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="info">
        <p class="mfg">Mfg 1</p>
        <h2 class="title"><a href="/product1.html">Product Name 1</a></h2>
        <div class="SKU">
          SKU #1
        </div>
      <p class="model">Model #1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="prodFeatures>
    <div class="inner">
      <a title="Product Name 2" class="img" href="/product2.html"><img alt='' src="/products/product2.jpg" /></a>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="info">
        <p class="mfg">Mfg 2</p>
        <h2 class="title"><a href="/product2.html">Product Name 2</a></h2>
        <div class="SKU">
          SKU #2
        </div>
      <p class="model">Model #2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I've tried a few different methods that I found through StackOverflow. This method appears to come the closest. (I didn't save the links, but that would have been helpful for everyone, wouldn't it?)

It seems like this should work:
(I've only shown that part of the sub that is responsible for grabbing the data. The rest of it works fine.)

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
Dim y As Integer 
Dim result As String

'set iteration counter
i = 1            
        'for each <a> element in the collection of objects with class of 'info'...
        For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("info")

        MsgBox (aEle)

            ' limit to 3 items returned per search term
            If i = 4 Then
            Exit For
            End If

            '...count result and print it to Sheet2 in col A
            Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = i
            Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireColumn.AutoFit
            Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            Debug.Print i

            '...print search terms used in Sheet2 in col B
            Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = searchCell
            Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).WrapText = False
            Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
            Debug.Print searchCell

            If InStr(aEle, "  ") = 1 Then
                Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = "Nothing Found"
                Debug.Print "Nothing Found"
                GoTo nextSearch
            Else
                '...get the description within the element and print it to Sheet2 in col C
                Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = aEle.innerText
                Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).WrapText = False
                Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
                Debug.Print paraText

            End If

               '...get the href link and print it to Sheet2 in col D, next blank row
                result = aEle
                Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = result
                Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).WrapText = False
                Worksheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).EntireColumn.AutoFit
                Debug.Print result

            'increment our iteration counter
            i = i + 1

        'repeat times the # of ele's we have in the collection

        Next aEle
```

Comment: I did some more research and learning and went a completely different (probably right) way.

The key part is that I extracted the href from the first a tag after the h2 tag with the classname of title. It was done like so:
Set aEle = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("title")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
                       MsgBox (aEle.href)
                       Debug.Print aEle.hr

The result is exactly what I was looking for - the URL of the product.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't seem to post it so the actual code I used was more readable.